# How to display result on the same page?

Tags: html, spring, file, thymeleaf

how can o display result below?
I want to upload two files and show result on the same page.
but it shows nothing( 
what am i doing wrong?

Controller

```
    @GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model){
    return "index";
}
    @RequestMapping( "uploadFiles")
public String handleFileUpload(Model model, @RequestParam("file1")MultipartFile file1, @RequestParam("file2")MultipartFile file2){
    if(!file1.isEmpty() || !file2.isEmpty()){
        if(!file1.getContentType().endsWith("mp3") || !file2.getContentType().endsWith("mp3")) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not Mp3");
        model.addAttribute("res", res);
        return "index";
    }else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty File");
    }
}
```

html

```
  <form role="form" method="POST"
          enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadFiles">
        <div class="text-left">
            File1 : <input type="file" class="btn btn-default btn-md" name="file1">
        </div>
        <div class="text-left">
            File2 : <input type="file" class="btn btn-default btn-md" name="file2">
        </div>
        <input type="submit"
               value="Upload" class="btn btn-default btn-md">> Press here to upload the file!
        <h1 th: text="${res}"></h1>
        <h1 th:text="${track}"></h1>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the `return "index";` leading to ? if it is different page than the form page try to return null or zero stick the current page.

Comment: return "index" leading to index.html, i checked) so i shouldn't return index if i  want to stay on the same page? Then what i need to return? I just want to show some result below this form.

Comment: i figured out, but i'm not sure is it a right way. I made method return ModelAndView and put index and res in it.